# Cannot delete file because it is open due to merger class (pdf)

Tags: java

I am getting the following error while running this code. I found that it happens because of the `merger.mergesPagesFromPdfFiles()` function. How can i prevent this to happen? I tried several things but nothing worked.

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Post\Klanten\10817 - TEST TEST\Factuur TEST TEST.pdf: (Translated) The process does not have access because the file is used by another process

```
Merger merger = new Merger();
merger.mergesPagesFromPdfFiles(filesToSend, getPathPostTS().toString() + "\\"
        + CustomFunctions.generatePersonalFileName("Documenten", client) + ".pdf");
//Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

//merger = null;
for (String file : filesToSend) {
    File fileEntry = new File(file);
    try {
        fileEntry.setWritable(true);
        java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(fileEntry.toPath());
        //Another way of trying to delete it
        if (fileEntry.delete()) {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName() + " is deleted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
System.out.println(folder.list());
if (folder.list().length > 0) {

    folder.delete();

} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FOLDER IS NIET LEEG, KIJK NA");
}
```

And here is the merger class creating the conflict.

```
public Merger() {

}



public void mergesPagesFromPdfFiles(List<String> pdfFiles, String outputFileLocation) {
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFileLocation);
        PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document,fos );
        writer.setMergeFields();
        document.open();

        for (String pdf : pdfFiles) {
            int index = pdf.lastIndexOf("\\");
            String pdfName = pdf.substring(index + 1, pdf.indexOf(".pdf"));
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            // if(reader.getNumberOfPages() < mergePageNr){
            // System.err.println("'" + pdfName + "' has not enough pages to
            // merge. Skipped to next pdf!");
            // continue;
            // }
            writer.addDocument(reader);
        }
        System.out.println("Files merged!");
        document.close();
        writer.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out!

edit: complete error plus changed code to close fos

> Files merged!
>       java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Post\Klanten\10817 - TEST TEST\Factuur TEST TEST.pdf: Het proces heeft geen toegang tot het bestand omdat het door een ander proces wordt gebruikt.
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
>       at generalClasses.Generator.sendAllFilesWithPost(Generator.java:243)
>       at factuurGen.FactuurGenerator.(FactuurGenerator.java:63)
>       at factuurGen.FactuurOptionPanel.generate(FactuurOptionPanel.java:31)
>       at view.MainView.generateAllDocuments(MainView.java:368)
>       at view.MainView.lambda$1(MainView.java:309)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Is the FileOuputStream created in the constructor of PdfCopy properly closed?

Comment: Please provide full stack trace for the exception and give a check once if you are closing your input/output streams once you are done with them.

Comment: I edited question like requested, i closed the FileOutputStream as well but didn't help

Comment: Can you add the below statements in finally block than in try block?
finally { document.close();
        writer.close();
        fos.close(); }

Comment: Have you opened the file on your system?

Comment: The file is not open on my system and If I comment out the merge function the files are getting deleted without a problem.

Comment: May we know why you are performing file deletion twice? I don't think that's necessary and may be causing this problem. Also, it's hard for us to figure out from the exception details in foreign language to find in which line exception is being raised. Please provide the line number/statements where the exception is being raised.

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader#45750kr7ekb maybe

Comment: RC got it right, I had to close the PdfReader first. This kept the documents open which caused the deletion operation to fail ( i tried to delete in several ways, that's why it is there twice)

How do i close this thread, or mark it as solved?